# Javascript / Special Character Issue with Oracle Apex

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to implement this example to highlight a cell in an Oracle Apex report : https://doyensys.com/blogs/interactive-report-cell-highlight-based-on-condition-using-jquery-dynamically/

My report uses a query which accesses a Function and returns the cell color (eg: **data-style="background-color:green"**).
This is step 1 in the above tutorial and works fine.

I have also completed step 2 and 3 successfully.

The problem, when I run the report, is that the background doesn't change. When I check the source code it is reading as

> < span data-style=& quot;background-color:green& quot;>DATA</ span>

What is causing the replacement of " with & quot; and how can I stop the Javascript from seeing it this way?

When I manually use the following it works fine:

> < span data-style="background-color:green">DATA</ span>

As per the tutorial I have specified **< span #CHK_ENTRY#>#ENTRY#</ span>** in the HTML Expression section.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can suppress the escaping. You might check the `CHK_ENTRY` column and see if Escape Special Characters is turned on.

What you can certainly do is change the HTML Expression to `<span data-style="#CHK_ENTRY#">...` and change your `CHK_ENTRY` column to just the CSS and not the whole attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I hadn't seen the "Escape Special Characters" toggle however this did not appear to work.

The second method works very well. Thanks for that and not sure why I didn't see it.

It would be helpful to know if it's possible to create strings in a Function and return them back to the page though. On another page I create the following string :

> {value: 1.19352}, {value: 1.19343}, {value: 1.19337}, {value: 1.19335}, {value: 1.19331}, ........

But when it returns to the page the source is showing it as :

> \u007Bvalue\u003A\u00201.19352\u007D, .......